# Get local workspaces with TeamFoundationServer.Client

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I've found a few examples of how to get local workspaces using the `TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`. However, on the Microsoft Docs page, it says, that the primary use case for that is

> Existing Windows apps leveraging an older version of the TFS Client OM. New work item and testing features will not be supported in this package. Please use the .NET Client Library based on REST.

I'm using VS2019 with TFS Server 2018, so I'd need to use `TeamFoundationServer.Client`, but I can't find a way to get local workspaces in there. Is there a way to do that, or do I need to use `ExtendedClient` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see any methods or official documents to work with workspaces in REST API. I think you need to use ExtendedClient or run tf.exe and parse it's results ([Workspaces Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workspaces-command?view=azure-devops))